# How to avoid escaping character in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am writing a small application that sends data to a server through REST API as simple URL calls. I use the RestSharp library to do this. My problem is, that some data strings I am sending include the `/` character.
I can't leave the character as it is, since the called URL would then be invalid. But when I replace it with `%2F` (which is then translated back on the server side), the RestSharp replaces the `%` character again, giving `%252F`. The Rest call than fails since server is missing the backslash.

I have [searched the web](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restsharp/doGE1a3vjDM) but found no working solution to this problem. Do you have any idea how to solve it, without using different library and rewriting it myself? Also, not using the backslash is NOT an option.

My code is here:

```
using RestSharp;  //Version 104       

private string RestRequest(string URL, RestSharp.Method Method)
{
    var Client = new RestClient();
    Client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(ID, Password);
    var Request = new RestRequest(URL, Method);
    IRestResponse Response = Client.Execute(Request);
    return Response.Content;
}
```

Sample URL that is passed to the function:

htp://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/knowledge-base-portlet.kbarticle/add-kb-article/portlet-id/1_WAR_knowledgebaseportlet/parent-resource-class-name-id/20704/parent-resource-prim-key/20200/title/SomeTitle/url-title/**%2F**Title/content/SomeContent

Comment: Have you also posted this in Restsharp's github?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the URL you're using?

Comment: I haven't posted it to the GitHub, since it does not look to be a bug, but a feature :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After snooping around Resharper's Github issues, like this [one](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/707), it seems you have to use `RestRequest.AddURLSegment()`. Tested with RestSharp v. 104.0.0

```
var url = "http://localhost:4422/api/jsonws/knowledge-base-portlet.kbarticle/add-kb-article/portlet-id/1_WAR_knowledgebaseportlet/parent-resource-class-name-id/20704/parent-resource-prim-key/20200/title/SomeTitle/url-title/{segment}/content/SomeContent";

var Client = new RestClient();
var Request = new RestRequest(url,Method.GET);
Request.AddUrlSegment("segment", "%2Ftitle");
```

I don't know if it's possible for you to pass multiple arguments. If you cannot, the simplest scenario would be splitting by `%2F` and concatenate multiple arguemnts. Something like this:

```
private string RestRequest(string URL, RestSharp.Method Method)
{
    var Client = new RestClient();

    string requestUrl;

    bool hasBackslashArgument = ParseEncodedBackSlash(URL, out requestUrl);

    RestRequest request;
    if (hasBackslashArgument)
    {
        request = new RestRequest(requestUrl, Method);
        request.AddUrlSegment("segment", "%2F");
    }
    else
    {
        request = new RestRequest(URL, Method);
    }

    IRestResponse response = Client.Execute(request);
    return response.Content;
}

private bool ParseEncodedBackSlash(string url, out string preformattedString)
{
    preformattedString = null;

    var urlSegments = url.Split(new string[] { "%2F" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    if (urlSegments.Length == 0) return false;

    preformattedString = string.Join("{segment}", urlSegments);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I already tried the URLSegment approach, but to no avail. But the link you posted suggests there may be difference between dll's using different versions of .net. I need to check that.

Comment: For SOME reason, your approach does not work for me. With the same configuration like you (RestSharp 104.0.0 and .Net 4.5.1), the %2F UrlSegment still gets encoded. Even when using your exact code.
If I use segment containing the / character, it remains untouched and screws the URL adress.

Comment: Sorry if this is stupid,  but in order to troubleshoot this,  are you able to do it in another machine?

Comment: That's a good question. Answer is no. Because of company policies I can only use one appointed machine :I

Comment: At the moment I can only help you next week. You are not allowed to update restsharp? Or test it in a project clone

Comment: Per company policy, I have one computer to do with as I please. Including updating restsharp. But no matter what release of restsharp I use, I can't get it to work. Anyway, thanks for your effort.